# Dynamic data type for a variable

Tags: abap

Usually, we declare table field as data type like this:

> DATA key TYPE vbak-vbeln.

However, I want to give field names dynamically in the declaration like so:

> DATA key TYPE vbak-**fieldname**.

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you try to describe why you want to declare the types dynamically?

Comment: check this out, trying to get a SAP stack exchange started http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily, if you use a Field Symbol of type any.

Then, it's as simple as:

```
DATA: lt_line type vbak.
Field-Symbols: <dat> type any.

Assign component (fieldname) of Structure lt_line to <dat>.
```

If you provide more info about what you are trying to do, perhaps I can offer a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped me. I posted my final answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case both table and field names are unknown. So this is my final solution.

```
DATA: T_REF TYPE REF TO DATA,
      TAB(20) TYPE c VALUE 'VBAP',
      TAB_COMP(20) TYPE c VALUE 'WERKS'.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <T> TYPE ANY,
               <COMP> TYPE ANY.

CREATE DATA T_REF TYPE (TAB).
ASSIGN T_REF->* TO <T>.
ASSIGN COMPONENT TAB_COMP OF STRUCTURE <T> TO <COMP>.

SELECT WERKS FROM VBAP INTO <COMP> UP TO 5 ROWS.
    WRITE: / <COMP>.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: @vwegert I can pass any table any field from my UI.